# MVC Chrome image full path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, file-io

I am not able to get the image full path in chrome but the same code working in IE. Whenever i select image from another location then it throw error as

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>       Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Chrysanthemum.jpg'.

Below is my `Controller` code

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,Name")] Employee employee, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string Name = @"C:\temp\yourfile.png";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Name, System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file.FileName));

        employee.image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file.FileName);
        db.Employees.Add(employee);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(employee);
}
```

Below is my `MVC` code

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save" />
```

Because of this issue i am not able to save the images anywhere.
Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are/can be couple of issues.

1. Don't use hard-coded local file-paths i.e C:\ etc, Make use of Server.Mappath
2. Also check for the resource you want to access (i.e. image in your case) is in same or underlying virtual directory of your MVC application
3. Also check if you have access permission on the said resource.

Unless you want to access a resource from another domain the above checks should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @Baua thanks for the reply. Actually i m not using hard coded path. it is occurred in exception. I am selecting the image from local system and wanted to save it in project location but for that itself it is throwing error.